# Schedule Serverless to specific function/endpoint

Tags: aws-lambda, cron, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, aws-event-bridge

I've set up an express api, a bunch of routes and am running them off a docker image.

I'm trying to setup a specific path in API Gateway to trigger every minute.

Going off: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/schedule/
I'm not quite sure how I achieve this and can't find any examples specific to my purposes.

My functions section in serveless.yml looks like:

```
functions:
  api:
    image:
      name: expressImage
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: ANY /{proxy+}
      - schedule:
          rate: rate(1 minute)
          enabled: true
```

With expressImage containing the necessary entrypoint's and running of specified routes (when run manually)

But I'd like to run a GET through API gateway at `/api_caching/schedule` every minute, with the schedule route/function within express handling the logic.

Any idea how/if I can do this from serverless.yml or do I need to make a hybrid EventBridge setup?

Should I be looking to run the entire express app and default route every minute then handling this by controller or can this be configured at a serverless/cloudformation level?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Is there a reason why it has to be called via API Gateway? The way you set it up right now, the function will be invoked every minute, but not through API Gateway.

Comment: Not particularly. 
I just need something that can run cron jobs and hit my internal endpoints/functions at given intervals. 
I've gotten this working by creating a simple schedule lambda that runs every minute and hits a number of other lambdas.

Comment: I know I can do this directly to lambda using the aws-sdk but it's the scheduler portion I'm trying to find the best solution for. If I were able to say (within the same serverless.yml) that /some_endpoint and /another_endpoint get scheduled at 1 and 10 minutes respectively, this would be what I'm trying to achieve - instead of basically creating my own warmer, which I've done atm

Comment: I think the best you could do is to create a function with a `schedule` event that during invocation calls these endpoints.